# Spring boot Wildfly deploy Swagger is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, wildfly

I deploy my spring boot application in wildfly recently I have to add swagger ui in my spring boot application. I have added that and its works locally but for some reason when I try to deploy my war file in the wildfly management console its show an error ( please see the image below ).I did not find a proper solution for the problem online.

**Verions-**

- spring boot - 2.7.3
- Java- 8
- wildfly - 10

**Error in wildfly management console**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN8J0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your war package doesn't have classes of validation-api. Ensure whether your war package contains the relevant package. Or else remove that @NotBlank annotation from your code.

Actual Maven Package which contains the missing class.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/

Comment: thank you it did work all I have to do was to add validation api in my pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is facing similar issue just add validation API to your pom.xml.

Thanks @Annamalai for your answer.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```